# How to show the result as text in a cell not the formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do you show the result as text in a cell not the formula, this is the what I'm using " =IF(Detail!C:C=$E$6,Detail!A:A,"") "to get the data from the details tab and returning it to my work sheet, but it will only show the formula string in the cell not the result, I need it to be the result as TEXT because I have to condition format the cell ...

thanks

Comment: Are the external quotes in the cell?

Comment: I also notice a space before the `=` of the formula, make sure to remove it if it's in the cell

Comment: Nothing looks wrong in the formula if written like this,,`=IF(Detail!C:C=$E$6,Detail!A:A,"")` for me it's working! If the cells are formatted as TEXT even. Check if by mistake formula presides with Apostrophe and formatted as Text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like two issues.

First, you don't need cell format set to `Text` for conditional formatting to work, just set it to `General` and Excel will handle it correctly.

Second, your formula won't work as written.  Try this instead:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Detail!A:A,MATCH($E$6,Detail!C:C,0),0),"")`

This is how this works:

`MATCH(lookup_value,lookup_array,match_type)`

`Match` will lookup the value in `$E$6` in the column `Detail!C:C` and return the row number where it is first found.  The match_type of `0` means that it will only return exact matches.  If it doesn't find a match, it will return an error.

`INDEX(array,row_num,column_num)`

`Index` will look in `Detail!A:A` and return the value in the row number that was returned in `Match`.  The column offset is `,0`.  You can just put the `,` but it's better to be explicit when you have to look at your formulas later.

`IFERROR(value,value_if_error)`

This captures the error returned if a match is not found and gives you the `""` that you wanted.

Comment: Sorry for the Late response, it worked a treat. Thank you very much. :-)